# css - Aligning issue

Tags: html, css

I want to do some design tweaks in my web application, but I'm stuck due to some alignment issues.

Please go to http://qlimp.com

Login username/password: `dummy/dummy`.

Then go to this link http://qlimp.com/information.

There you can find Keywords **input text** with the **add button** at the bottom which is not positioned properly. I can't change the position of the `input text`. But when you remove that add button (`#add-button`), we can change the position of that `#add-keywords` input text. Why is this so?

Could anyone guide me to position it properly?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/RxHuN/

What I need is, I want the add button to be place on the input text and it want's to be movable, I mean changing positions

Comment: You'll likely get better answers if you create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) rather than make folks wade through your pages.

Comment: ok. I will show it in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```css
#add-keywords{
   float:left;
}

#add-button{
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   bottom:8px
}
```